# Why does R freeze when I initialize SpacyR?

Tags: r, spacy, named-entity-recognition, quanteda

Every time I successfully install spacyR with `spacy_install()`, but whenever I run `spacy_initialize`, my R console shows that it registers the code, but absolutely nothing happens and subsequently I cannot run any other code. How do I get spacyR to run properly?

I have tried to search for reasons why this would happen, to no avail. I have also tried redownloading and installing newer versions of Python and R.

Comment: No one can answer this question until you provide some information about your session and system (try: `sessionInfo()`). Also this should be an issue on the GitHub repo for spacyr, not a SO question.

Comment: I had a similar issue; I uninstall the reticulate developer version and reinstalled it from cran. It RSudio no longer crashes. I used developer version of space. The main steps for installation are given in this link https://github.com/quanteda/spacyr.

Comment: I am having a similar issue with spacy installation on my Macbook, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link providing some solutions: https://github.com/quanteda/spacyr/issues/236#issuecomment-1702311825

---

Either you can build the conda environment yourself:

In the anaconda terminal:

`conda install -n spacy_condaenv spacy -y`

`conda activate spacy_condaenv`

`python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

`conda activate base`

---

Or you can install a development version of spacyr where the bug is fixed:

In R:

`remotes::install_github("JBGruber/spacyr")`

---

Then load and initialize spacyr in R to see if it worked:

`library(spacyr)`

`spacy_install()`

`spacy_initialize()`